# Linking numbered styles in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word

In Word 2007, I'm trying to create a template with numbered headers, and I'm using numbered styles with outline levels. The outline works, but the lower level numbers don't reset after each higher level header, i.e.:

1. Header 1

   1. Subpart 1
   2. Subpart 2
2. Header 2

   **3.** Subpart 1

How can I make the numbers reset?

The styles are based on header 1, header 2, etc.

I can't use a multi-level list (unless it can be done automatically when applying the styles) because that would complicate the stuff under each sub-header.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the number 3 and click on **Restart at 1**

Comment: I know that it can be done manually - I want it to automatically restart after each higher-level header.

Answer (score 0):

## Create Labels

You could define your own sequence which resets after each "heading 1" to 1. You do this by typing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> and inserting "SEQ subheading \* Arabic \s 1 \* MERGEFORMAT" into the curly brackets. It looks this way:

```
{ SEQ subheading \* Arabic \s 1 \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

Through "\s 1" resets the sequence after each "heading 1" ("\s 2" would do this for "heading 2" etc.). "subheading" is just an identifier for your sequence. You can change it as you want.

## Auto-Insert Labels

see [Numbering equations based on chapter numbers in MS-Word](https://superuser.com/questions/241967/numbering-equations-based-on-chapter-numbers-in-ms-word/)

## Referencing

Unfortunately, the numbers are not automatically cross-reference-able. You need to set bookmarks manually as described here: [Numbering equations based on chapter numbers in MS-Word](https://superuser.com/questions/241967/numbering-equations-based-on-chapter-numbers-in-ms-word) .