# Modify entire document equation captions

Tags: microsoft-word

i've prepared a document containing 20 numbered equations that look like: 1-1 , i want to change all of them to look like: (1-1).

I followed this guide for numbering the equations -
[How do you easily add equation numbers to Microsoft Word 2010 equations?](https://superuser.com/questions/594559/how-do-you-easily-add-equation-numbers-to-microsoft-word-2010-equations)

i think it is a basic routine for organizing equations in scientific document.

tried some methods that was suggested , but none of them really helped. 
such simple task , turn to complicated one , only with Word...

anyone here can help ?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We need more details to be able to help you. You commented to the answer below "it is automated numbering using captions". Please [edit] your question to give more details about how you added the "equations" to the document.

Comment: edited , is it clearer now ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't perfect, but it might work for you:

1. Open the document in MS Word, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
2. Enter `(<[0-9]@>)-(<[0-9]@>)` in the `Find What` box
3. Enter `(\1-\2)` in the `Replace With` box and keep hitting the `Find Next` button to see if it correctly matches what you want it to match
4. If you're satisfied, press `Replace All`

Comment: nothing found, maybe is because it is automated numbering using caption