# Nothing is saved in Word 2013 when shutting of PC (macros, cross-references)

Tags: microsoft-word

exhausted and frustrated with word...

every day when I am working on the same document I have to start fresh with the macros I've made... or when I want to cross reference an equation that is captioned , I don't see it in the list of captioned equations that i wrote (under cross-reference -> reference type).

yesterday it worked.

I can see that the equations numbers are caption and also when i right click on it i can see the toggle field code - that is for me that word recognized it as a caption :

```
({STYLE REF 1 \s}-{SEQ ThesisEq\* ARABIC \s 1})
```

"ThesisEq" is the label of the caption - and now i cant see it when i press "InsertCaption"

Comment: Do you mean that your VBA macro's are disappearing? What happens if you make a change to the ribbon - is that saved?

Comment: yesterday i made a macro that when I press "Ctrl + \" it's inserting a numbered equation (like what explained (http://superuser.com/questions/594559/how-do-you-easily-add-equation-numbers-to-microsoft-word-2010-equations) today i opened word and when i pressed Ctrl +\ i got nothing. checked in View Macros dialog and nothing appears there... like it didn't save it.

Comment: also when i checking the dialog of insert caption i don't see the captions that i used for numbering the equations which called "TheiseEq" as i mentioned...

Comment: Any other changes that you make in Word are that saved?  Like what @JulianKnight asked.  If not it may be that the normal.dot template that saves all the settings may be broken.

Comment: I've re-installed word and created again the first caption and copy pasted it to all other equations , update "alt+f9" as for the macros , also created them one more time and verified that all are saved to normal.dotm. hoping that will work ... starting to write my thesis and very concerned word will screw me up...