# Referencing to Equations in word 2010 - problems with parantheses

Tags: microsoft-word, equations, equation-editor, cross-reference

I use equation referencing word, in particular a solution on using a table with equation numbering suggested here [how easily add equation numbers in word](https://superuser.com/questions/594559/how-do-you-easily-add-equation-numbers-to-microsoft-word-2010-equations).

In addition, I want to add parantheses arround the equation number so, for example (1.1). I did this manually in the template created in the link given above. So I added ( and ) left and right of the equation number and saved it as a formula template. With each new template added, there is now a nice equation number in parantheses (1.2)... that is automatically created.

However, now I want to cross-reference the euqation. When I add the complete labeling it will add (1.1). However, now I want only the number. When I select 'only category and number' it will add

(1.1

If I select add only label it inserts

)

This is strange, but reproducible, if you just create a simple equation number and add parantheses. Now add a cross-reference in the way described above and hte problem occurs. Is there a way to avoid this and only get the number?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be that "(" is recognized to be part of the number format but ")" not. I have no idea how to solve this issue with cross referencing the equation number. My suggestion is a workaround.

What I am doing to avoid this problem is setting a bookmark for "1.1" (not on "(1.1)") and cross-referencing the bookmark.

I got this solution from here: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/possible-to-have-a-linked-autonumber-field.2850387/