# M/S Word 2010 equation numbering: add a "table equation" to the equation gallery?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I'm too new here to add this as a comment so I'll try it as a new question.

I tried to follow the instructions in the best answer to this question:
[How do you easily add equation numbers to Microsoft Word 2010 equations](https://superuser.com/questions/594559/how-do-you-easily-add-equation-numbers-to-microsoft-word-2010-equations)
but when I highlight the entire table as instructed in step 14, "insert equation" gets grayed out (step 15 and the last step -- things were going so well too!).  Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

The answer was given by @r-Schultz but that user hasn't been seen in a couple of months. I hope the @ works to send them a note though.

https://superuser.com/users/148033/r-schultz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If at first you don't succeed: Since there were no responses yet I tried again.  Even though "Insert/Equations" is grayed out, I clicked on it anyway and "Save Selection" was NOT grayed out.

So it worked even though it looked like it might not.