# Error in microsoft word after writing numbered equations

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

I'm correcting a technical document (for English mistakes etc...) and I often meet problems like the following:

[image: image with the problem]

I.e. every time I start a new paragraph the parser complaints about the first word which doesn't start with a capital letter, the formulae are written using [How do you easily add equation numbers to Microsoft Word 2010 equations?](https://superuser.com/questions/594559/how-do-you-easily-add-equation-numbers-to-microsoft-word-2010-equations)

Comment: Given the large number of English mistakes in your question, perhaps someone else should be doing the corrections?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out... but i would prefer an answer to my question... (i.e. word related), and by the way... i wrote that document i need to make it as much presentable as possible...

Comment: The "where" is correct as it is part of the previous sentence. However it should be "where:". The "while" should be "While" as it is a new sentence. "for basic" should be "for the basic". "form" should be "form:". Each "as" at the end of a line should be "as:".

Comment: I've corrected the rest of your question.

Comment: Note Word grammar checking is not perfect, particularly when you do things like insert equations in between (partial) sentences. You should be able to right click on the green words and accept or reject the suggested changes.

Comment: yes but what i would like to achieve is one of the two following things:
1. avoid the green whatever thing i write after a formula.
2. a better e more suitable way to add numbered equations rather than the one i showed on the second link i posted.