# How add heading numbering ms-word?

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-word-2016, microsoft-word-2019

I want to create a format for my equation that is like this:

[image]

But i am struggle at giving numbering like that. I have google it many times but can't find any solution fit to me. I have explored "Insert Field" feature many times but nothing works for me

I want to do that the numbering in that picture -> II-2 , use this format- [Heading 1 Number]-[Sequential Number According to the heading 1]

So in result that the numbering will follow that rule and may give result like

```
II-1
II-2
III-1
III-2
III-3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you easily add equation numbers to Microsoft Word 2010 equations?](https://superuser.com/questions/594559/how-do-you-easily-add-equation-numbers-to-microsoft-word-2010-equations)

Comment: @harrymc I already use the table solution but struggle in numbering with the format that i want

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be simple:

- You already use a table to align the equation and sequence parts,
  as detailed in the post
   [How do you easily add equation numbers to Microsoft Word 2010 equations?](https://superuser.com/questions/594559/how-do-you-easily-add-equation-numbers-to-microsoft-word-2010-equations)
- In the text for the numbering part, add fields as follows:

  - For the section number in roman numerals, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>
    and enter the text
    `SECTION  \* ROMAN  \* MERGEFORMAT`
  - For a running count create a field with the contents of `seq ident`
    (see [link](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T008180_Numbering_with_Sequence_Fields.html))
- To show/hide all field contents in the document, press
  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>
- To re-calculate all fiels, select all using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
  then press <kbd>F9</kbd>