# Numbering multi-level lists in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I created a multilevel list with numbers for the headings. The hierarchy works with the headings. Now, I need to have regular list numbers under each heading that continue the heading number. If the heading number is 1. I need a numbered item that is 1.1 but is not a heading. Headings with number and items with numbers need to be available in any order. I can't find anything anywhere to explain how to do this.

1. Heading 1
   1.1 Heading 2
2. Heading 1
   2.1 Item (not a heading)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my solution here ([Numbering equations based on chapter numbers in MS-Word](https://superuser.com/questions/241967/numbering-equations-based-on-chapter-numbers-in-ms-word/)) helps you:

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>, insert "STYLEREF 1 \s", press <kbd>F9</kbd>, press <kbd>.</kbd>, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>, insert "SEQ eqn \* Arabic \s 1 \* MERGEFORMAT" and press <kbd>F9</kbd>.

It should look this way without pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>

```
{ STYLEREF 1 \s }.{ SEQ eqn \* Arabic \s 1 \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

and this way with pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>

```
1.1
```

Please see [Numbering equations based on chapter numbers in MS-Word](https://superuser.com/questions/241967/numbering-equations-based-on-chapter-numbers-in-ms-word/) on how it actually works and how you can reference these numbers.