# Word: Restarting SEQ numbering for equations in next chapter not working

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using Word from Microsoft 365. Using the approach from this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/241967/numbering-equations-based-on-chapter-numbers-in-ms-word) basically works, however, when I use my own templates for the headings it does not work anymore.

I get: 1.1 -> 1.2 -> 2.3 -> 2.4 -> 3.5

I want: 1.1 -> 1.2 > 2.1 -> 2.2 -> 3.1

The code I am using is `{STYLEREF "Sample1" \n}.{SEQ eq \s "Sample1"}` and the name of my template is named "Sample1". Besides, my headings, which are seperating the equations are all using this template. The strange thing is that styleref seems to be accepting "Sample1" but SEQ is not.

I know about \r but I want to use the same field all the time without the \r-exception for the first equation in each chapter.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The `\s` switch only works with the Built-In Heading Styles.

Here is the [online documentation for the Sequence Field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-seq-sequence-field-062a387b-dfc9-4ef8-8235-29ee113d59be?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us). The built-in heading styles have special, almost magical, properties in Microsoft Word. Here is Word MVP Shauna Kelly's [writing on reasons to use them](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/10HeadingStyles.htm). See #5 on Chapter numbering for Captions. Only the built in Heading Styles are available.

Note that when using the \s switch you refer to the *level* of the heading style rather than the *name* of the style. That is `\s 7` for Heading 7, not `\s Heading 7`. The Built-In heading styles are the only ones like this.

You can modify the appearance of the built-in heading styles. To use automatic numbering with them, do not simply apply numbering. Instead, use the Define New Multi-Level List dialog as described in [Shauna Kelly's page on Outline Numbering and Headings](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html).

Once you have the heading style(s) set up, you can use the Replace function to change the style for all of your headings.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I noticed, that these headings have something, that doesn't meet the users eye. I was not able to find the property, which makes them so "magical". I followed you suggestions and so far I can work quite well with them. I also stumbled over your advice regarding multi-level list more than once. I will check to properly apply it.

Comment: Glad to have helped.